# Bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap template in my project.
I used bootstrap datetimepicker for selecting date.
with html it works fine.
but when I used jquery methods to set options of datetimepicker,it opens two calendar one is to given textbox,and other is at top left corner of screen.

my code is
HTML

```
<p>Select Date</p>
<div class="input-icon datetime-pick date-only">
  <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"   id="date"/>
  <span class="add-on">
   <i class="sa-plus"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Jquery method

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#date").datetimepicker( {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    startDate: '2015-01-01',
    endDate: '2015-02-12'

  });
});
```

Comment: check the duplicate references of script files. ie jquery and bootstrap js files.

Comment: yes checked.I have included only once

Comment: Are you using this datetimepicker ?. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#bootstrap-3-datepicker-v4-docs

Comment: Could you provide a  code snippet so we could investigate more. :)

Comment: Why are you specifying to data-formats one as an attribute and one as options in js?

Comment: @ anpsmn,  data-format is by default attributes,Ok i can change it in HTML.But How could i set other options

Comment: @ vikrantx , Yes I am using same kind of datetimepicker